# Displaying xml float data

Tags: android, xml

I am trying to create an earthquake watcher app but I can't seem to get the coordinates and other sections from the XML URL to show on my activity when I load the project I know that they are of type float. I have tried different methods and I have no errors on the console so it must be something with the way that I am calling it??
I have added some output and images

```
package ja.example.mpd1starterearth;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser;
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException;
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserFactory;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ListView lvRss;
    ArrayList<String> titles;
    ArrayList<String> links;
    ArrayList<Double> lat;
    ArrayList<Double> lon;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        lvRss = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvRss);

        titles = new ArrayList<String>();
        links = new ArrayList<String>();
        lat = new ArrayList<Double>();
        lon = new ArrayList<Double>();

        lvRss.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                Uri uri = Uri.parse(links.get(position));
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });

        new ProcessInBackground().execute();
    }

    public InputStream getInputStream(URL url)
    {
        try
        {
            //openConnection() returns instance that represents a connection to the remote object referred to by the URL
            //getInputStream() returns a stream that reads from the open connection
            return url.openConnection().getInputStream();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public class ProcessInBackground extends AsyncTask<Integer, Void, Exception>
    {
        ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);

        Exception exception = null;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

            progressDialog.setMessage("Busy loading rss feed...please wait...");
            progressDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected Exception doInBackground(Integer... params) {

            try
            {
                URL url = new URL("http://quakes.bgs.ac.uk/feeds/MhSeismology.xml");

                //creates new instance of PullParserFactory that can be used to create XML pull parsers
                XmlPullParserFactory factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();

                //Specifies whether the parser produced by this factory will provide support
                //for XML namespaces
                factory.setNamespaceAware(false);

                //creates a new instance of a XML pull parser using the currently configured
                //factory features
                XmlPullParser xpp = factory.newPullParser();

                // We will get the XML from an input stream
                xpp.setInput(getInputStream(url), "UTF_8");

                /* We will parse the XML content looking for the "<title>" tag which appears inside the "<item>" tag.
                 * We should take into consideration that the rss feed name is also enclosed in a "<title>" tag.
                 * Every feed begins with these lines: "<channel><title>Feed_Name</title> etc."
                 * We should skip the "<title>" tag which is a child of "<channel>" tag,
                 * and take into consideration only the "<title>" tag which is a child of the "<item>" tag
                 *
                 * In order to achieve this, we will make use of a boolean variable called "insideItem".
                 */
                boolean insideItem = false;

                // Returns the type of current event: START_TAG, END_TAG, START_DOCUMENT, END_DOCUMENT etc..
                int eventType = xpp.getEventType(); //loop control variable

                while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT)
                {
                    //if we are at a START_TAG (opening tag)
                    if (eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG)
                    {
                        //if the tag is called "item"
                        if (xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("item"))
                        {
                            insideItem = true;
                        }
                        //if the tag is called "title"
                        else if (xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("title"))
                        {
                            if (insideItem)
                            {
                                // extract the text between <title> and </title>
                                titles.add(xpp.nextText());
                            }
                        }
                        //if the tag is called "link"
                        else if (xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("link"))
                        {
                            if (insideItem)
                            {
                                // extract the text between <link> and </link>
                                links.add(xpp.nextText());
                            }
                        }
                        else if(xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("geo:lat")){
                            if(insideItem){
                                //extract the text between <geo:lat> and </geo:lat>
                                lat.add(Double.valueOf(xpp.nextText()));
                            }
                        }
                        else if(xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("geo:long")){
                            if(insideItem) {
                                //extract the text between <geo:lat> and </geo:lat>
                                lon.add(Double.valueOf(xpp.nextText()));;
                            }  }
                    }
                    //if we are at an END_TAG and the END_TAG is called "item"
                    else if (eventType == XmlPullParser.END_TAG && xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("item"))
                    {
                        insideItem = false;
                    }

                    eventType = xpp.next(); //move to next element
                }


            }
            catch (MalformedURLException e)
            {
                exception = e;
            }
            catch (XmlPullParserException e)
            {
                exception = e;
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                exception = e;
            }

            return exception;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Exception s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);

            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, titles);

            lvRss.setAdapter(adapter);


            progressDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you show the code which you get xml from url and parse it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code to parse data from the URL is totally correct. You do not see all data all the activity because this line of code.

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, titles);
```

You pass `titles` arraylist to the adapter, that why you only see all title xml value in the activity.

**Solution:** The simple way is format the data which connect from 4 array list `titles`, `links`, `lat`, `lon`.

```
/**
 * This method will format data from titles, links, lat, lon arraylist.
 */
private List<String> formatDataBeforeDisplayOnListView(){
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    int size = titles.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        String title = titles.get(i);
        String link = links.get(i);
        Double geoLat = lat.get(i);
        Double getLon = lon.get(i);

        sb.append("title: ").append(title).append("\n")
          .append("link: ").append(link).append("\n")
          .append("geo-lat: ").append(geoLat).append("\n")
          .append("geo-lon: ").append(getLon);

        list.add(sb.toString());
    }

    return list;
}
```

Then change your code to

```
// Comment-out this line
// ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, titles);

List<String> items = formatDataBeforeDisplayOnListView();
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items);
```

**Note:** If you want to display each item listview in a better design/UI then you should write a custom adapter class instead of `ArrayAdapter`.

**Updated:** Based on Jase's comment

First, declare a new class named `Item`

```
public class Item {
    private String title;
    private String link;
    private Double lat;
    private Double lon;

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getLink() {
        return link;
    }

    public void setLink(String link) {
        this.link = link;
    }

    public Double getLat() {
        return lat;
    }

    public void setLat(Double lat) {
        this.lat = lat;
    }

    public Double getLon() {
        return lon;
    }

    public void setLon(Double lon) {
        this.lon = lon;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return (new StringBuilder()).append("title: ").append(title).append("\n")
                .append("link: ").append(link).append("\n")
                .append("geo-lat: ").append(lat).append("\n")
                .append("geo-lon: ").append(lon).toString();
    }
}
```

Then, change your activity code to

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ListView lvRss;
    ArrayList<Item> mItems = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        lvRss = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvRss);
        lvRss.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                // TODO: Process clicked item here
                Item item = (Item) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);

                Uri uri = Uri.parse(item.getLink());
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        new ProcessInBackground().execute();
    }

    public InputStream getInputStream(URL url) {
        try {
            //openConnection() returns instance that represents a connection to the remote object referred to by the URL
            //getInputStream() returns a stream that reads from the open connection
            return url.openConnection().getInputStream();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public class ProcessInBackground extends AsyncTask<Integer, Void, Exception> {
        ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);

        Exception exception = null;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

            progressDialog.setMessage("Busy loading rss feed...please wait...");
            progressDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected Exception doInBackground(Integer... params) {

            try {
                URL url = new URL("http://quakes.bgs.ac.uk/feeds/MhSeismology.xml");

                //creates new instance of PullParserFactory that can be used to create XML pull parsers
                XmlPullParserFactory factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();

                //Specifies whether the parser produced by this factory will provide support
                //for XML namespaces
                factory.setNamespaceAware(false);

                //creates a new instance of a XML pull parser using the currently configured
                //factory features
                XmlPullParser xpp = factory.newPullParser();

                // We will get the XML from an input stream
                xpp.setInput(getInputStream(url), "UTF_8");

                /* We will parse the XML content looking for the "<title>" tag which appears inside the "<item>" tag.
                 * We should take into consideration that the rss feed name is also enclosed in a "<title>" tag.
                 * Every feed begins with these lines: "<channel><title>Feed_Name</title> etc."
                 * We should skip the "<title>" tag which is a child of "<channel>" tag,
                 * and take into consideration only the "<title>" tag which is a child of the "<item>" tag
                 *
                 * In order to achieve this, we will make use of a boolean variable called "insideItem".
                 */
                boolean insideItem = false;

                // Returns the type of current event: START_TAG, END_TAG, START_DOCUMENT, END_DOCUMENT etc..
                int eventType = xpp.getEventType(); //loop control variable

                Item item = null;
                while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
                    //if we are at a START_TAG (opening tag)
                    if (eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
                        //if the tag is called "item"
                        if (xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("item")) {
                            insideItem = true;
                            item = new Item();
                        }
                        //if the tag is called "title"
                        else if (xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("title")) {
                            if (insideItem) {
                                // extract the text between <title> and </title>
                                item.setTitle(xpp.nextText());
                            }
                        }
                        //if the tag is called "link"
                        else if (xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("link")) {
                            if (insideItem) {
                                // extract the text between <link> and </link>
                                item.setLink(xpp.nextText());
                            }
                        } else if (xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("geo:lat")) {
                            if (insideItem) {
                                //extract the text between <geo:lat> and </geo:lat>
                                item.setLat(Double.valueOf(xpp.nextText()));
                            }
                        } else if (xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("geo:long")) {
                            if (insideItem) {
                                //extract the text between <geo:lat> and </geo:lat>
                                item.setLon(Double.valueOf(xpp.nextText()));
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    //if we are at an END_TAG and the END_TAG is called "item"
                    else if (eventType == XmlPullParser.END_TAG && xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("item")) {
                        insideItem = false;
                        mItems.add(item);
                    }

                    eventType = xpp.next(); //move to next element
                }

            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                exception = e;
            } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
                exception = e;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                exception = e;
            }

            return exception;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Exception s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);

            ArrayAdapter<Item> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, mItems);
            lvRss.setAdapter(adapter);

            progressDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: wow Tommy, thank you so much that had me stumped....okay since I have you here do you have any idea how to add a function where I set an onclickevent listener to the outputted list view so that when I click on an item it can be displayed on a map I have seen various tutorials but I don't quite get it....if you can help that would be great as I can get through the rest by myself I think...thanks again for helping me out

Comment: Thats awesome Tommy, so if I were to plot these on a map would I just create an arrayList to store the lat and lon data returned and add a map to the project then create a function to plot on the map as I want to either select them individually or even just have an option to go to map view and display them all at once with markers....you see..thanks again by the way I am learning so much

Comment: Based on your requirement, you can display all markers on map and handle event when user click on each marker. By the way, if my answer solved your problem then you can mark it as answer. It will help me improve my answers in future.

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing tag name with space in it thus `equalsIgnoreCase()` will always return `false` as `geo:lang` will not be equal to `geo :lat`.

Just test this code.

```
String s = "geo:lang";
System.out.println(""+s.equalsIgnoreCase("geo :long"));
```

You need to remove space in between `o` and `:` for both cases eg.`equalsIgnoreCase("geo:long")`

Comment: Hi thanks so much for answering, I amended that mistake but I still don't get the display.I just get the previous output still no errors though...

Comment: try clean and build at first. also try debugging to see that values are fetched or not.

Comment: still nothing but I know that the values are being accessed because when I put in the wrong return type earlier I received an error stating that 51.345 needed type float...with was data from the url...